# Get the gradient at a specific point in a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a plot as shown in this picture. [image: Plot] I would like to get the gradient at a specific value of t. For example, the gradient of the curve at the very last value of t (end of the curve). May I know how I can achieve this?

The code for the plot is as shown below:

```
T = Drop[FoldList[Plus, 0, x], 1];
Subscript[plot, ref] = 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{T, Range[m]}], Joined -> True, AxesLabel -> {"t^ ", "N(t)^ "}, PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Z\), \(ref\)]\)"}]
```

Comment: Your code does not work. You did not include the definitions of `m` and `x`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

The "gradient" is the extension of the derivative to multidimensions. But in your case you have only 1 dimension, so it is the derivative.

As you code does not work, I create some sample arbitrary  data:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat0 = Table[Log[x] + 0.1 RandomReal[], {x, 1, 10, 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[dat0]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

As the derivative will enhance the noise we first need to smooth the data. Towards this aim,I use arbitrarily a fit with a simple polynomial, but many other methods may be used:

```
fit = Fit[dat, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x]
Plot[fit, {x, 1, 91}]

(* 0.315501 + 0.0442448 x - 0.000326861 x^2 + 9.03264*10^-7 x^3 *)
```

[image]

Having a function, we may calculate the derivative:

```
der = D[fit, x];
Plot[der, {x, 1, 91}]

(* 0.0442448 - 0.000653722 x + 2.70979*10^-6 x^2 *)
```

[image]

To get the derivative at some point, e.g. at the end, we may simply evaluate the derivative at the corresponding x:

```
der /. x -> 91
(* 0.00719581 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

A derivative from noisy data might not be very insightful.

Taking the example data from @DanielHuber and including the abscissas :

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat0 = Table[{x, Log[x] + 0.1* RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}];
Show[ListLinePlot[dat0]]
```

[image: data]

Up to a scaling factor from the inverse step spacing, the derivative would look like:

```
Differences[dat0[[All, 2]]] // ListPlot
```

[image: derivative]

#### Local fit

Although I have not used it myself you might want to consider the resource function [ListD](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ListD/) which seems adapted to this scenario (**Note :** Resource functions might not be as reliable as native functions as they are not necessarily made by members of the Wolfram team, you can check the source notebook of the function for how it was made).

ListD uses fits with a local window size. From the documentation, the options to choose from are forward, backward or center differences or FFT if the spacing is uniform.

Using that with the example before:

```
Show[ResourceFunction["ListD"][dat0, "WindowSize" -> 2^#] & /@ 
Range[3] // ListPlot, Plot[1/x, {x, 1, 10}]]
```

[image: windowsize]

Which shows smoother local plots as the window size increases but with window sizes that are too large one might miss important aspects of the function.

#### Global functional fit

If you would like the derivative from a function that smooths the data globally then the question is not well defined without prior knowledge on what generated the data. Specifically, without a model or information on what kind of functions could be in the model, there is a lot of ways to smooth the data.

For example, `FindFormula` is able to average out the 0.1*RandomReal[] noise.

```
b = FindFormula[dat0, s]
```

Out:  `(* 0.0499583 + Log[s] *)`

The actual average over the noise would be `0.05+Log[s]`.

(**Note:** The function above is for the data provided by @DanielHuber. Not the plot you provided.)

With that function you can take the derivative.

However, `FindFormula` was a bit lucky as the function was simple. We can shift and scale the argument to obtain a new function:

```
SeedRandom[1];
dat0 = Table[{x, Log[10*x + 3] + 0.1*RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10, 0.1}];
```

And we will obtain new predictions from `FindFormula` (different results appear each time we evaluate the code):

```
FindFormula[dat0, s, 3][[1;;2]]


(* {2.17998 + 0.755664 s - 0.202978 s^1.40088, 2.09074 + 0.65601 s - 
0.0674422 s^2 + 0.00279957 s^3} *)
```

All these functions are reasonably good fits for the function:

```
Show[Plot[b, {s, 1, 10}], ListLinePlot[dat0]]
```

[image: comparison]

But there derivatives differ

```
Plot @@ {D[b, s]~Join~{D[Log[10*s + 3], s]}, {s, 1, 10}}
```

[image: comparison]

That, said I purposely looked for functions that visually looked not too bad but whose derivatives were bad to highlight the potential risk.

If we do not ask `FindFormula` to make more than 1 approximation it seems it gives a nice result but I do not have much experience with this function.

```
b2 = FindFormula[dat0, s]
```

Out: `(* 47.8744 - 45.3384/s^0.0208484 *)`

The fit is reasonable

```
Show[Plot[b2, {s, 1, 10}], ListLinePlot[dat0]]
```

[image: comparison]

and the derivative is not too far from the derivative of the original function.

```
Plot @@ {{D[b2, s], D[Log[10*s + 3], s]}, {s, 1, 10}}
```

[image: derivative]

That said, I still think it is imprecise at best and risky at worse to not specify what kind of processes generated the data or to not have an idea of the model.

If you have an idea what the model might look like  you could use [`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) or [`Fit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html).